# Gem development in a rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I am working on a gem, which I'd like to finalize inside a Rails (3) project. The gem is build with jeweler.

The gem works, but has quite a few rough edges and TODOs. I have (some) tests, and they all pass. I want to work on it a bit more, by implementing it in a Rails project.

What workflow should I use? Are there bundler, jeweler or rake commands for this kind of workflow? Or should I place the "source" (unbuild gem) somewhere in my rails app and have Rails pick it magically? Are there other tricks or projects to look at?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just place something like this in your Rails project's  Gemfile:

```
gem 'yourgem', :path => "~/Workspace/yourgem"
```

where `~/Workspace/yourgem` points to the location where you are doing active gem development on your computer.